# Cannot remove the ReadOnly property from folder

Tags: vb.net, attributes, directory

I'm trying to remove the read-only property of a directory but I can't do it.

```
  Private _attributes As FileAttributes = FileAttributes.Normal

  Private Sub RemoveReadOnlyDirectoryAttributes(ByVal path As String)
        'Check root folder
        Dim di As New DirectoryInfo(path)
        di.Attributes = _attributes

        'Check sub folders
        For Each folder As String In Directory.GetDirectories(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            di = New DirectoryInfo(folder)
            di.Attributes = _attributes
        Next

    End Sub
```

I would have thought this code updates the attributes to Normal.

However, when I right click on the directory I see

[image]

I have also seen posts here on SO where they apply a method similar to

```
    Dim di As New DirectoryInfo(path)
    di.Attributes =  di.attributes And Not FileAttributes.ReadOnly
```

but this doesn't help either.

I am admin of the machine.

Comment: When you enter the method could you check which value is assigned to  Attributes enum? There is the readonly flag assigned? I ask because the flag in the image showed is not used to indicate a readonly directory

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing read only attribute on a directory using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866906/removing-read-only-attribute-on-a-directory-using-c-sharp)